# Application error with shared session

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried converting some code from a tutorial as best I can but it doesn't seem to work, at the moment, its giving

> Invalid conversion from throwing function

On the `let task` line.

```
func request(url:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()) {
  do{

    var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)

    let task = try NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!){
        (data, response, error) in
        var error:NSError?

        var response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as NSDictionary
        callback(response)

    }
   task.resume()
  }
  catch{
       print(error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `try` from `NSURLSession.sharedSession`.

```
func request(url:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()) {

    let url = NSURL(string: url)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
        var error:NSError?
        do {
            var response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            callback(response)
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```